# Append to list of dictionary dumped in json without loading the list out with python

Tags: python, json

In python, I know that I can dump a list of dictionaries in .json file for storage with `json.dump()` from the `json` module. However, after dumping a list, is it possible to append more dictionaries to that list in the `.json` file without explictly read load the full list, append, then dump the list again?

e.g.
In `.json` I have

```
[{'a': 1}]
```

Is it possible to add `{'b', 2}` to the list in `.json` such that the file become

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b', 2}]
```

The actual list is much longer (on the order of ten million), so I'm wondering if there're more direct ways of doing that without reading the entire list from the file to save memory.

Edit:

PS: I'm also open to other file format as long as it can effectively store a large list of dictionaries and can achieve the function above

Comment: JSON is not a suitable format for this. Have a look at [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: What do you mean by "_without explictly read load the full list, append, then dump the list again_"? You had saved list in file and you don't want to read that file?

Comment: @Kshitiz Well I can read the file but I am trying to avoid reading out the entire list (`json.load()` into a variable which can take a hugr amount of memory)

Comment: Had you tried to just open file from `notepad` and write. Sorry, but I am not sure you are in windows or other os. But, if the file is large and you just want to add 2/3 things only, then you may try it. I am not sure it will work or not, so I am not posting it as answer, please inform me after try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this can be a simple file manipulation problem under the right circumstances. If you are sure that the root data structure of the dump is indeed a json array, you can delete the last "]" in the file and then append a new dump to the file.

You can append with the dumps function.

```py
from json import dumps, dump
import os

#This represents your current dump call
with open('out.json', 'w') as f:
    dump([{'version':1}], f)

# This removes the final ']'
with open('out.json', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()

#This appends the new dictionary
with open('out.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(',')
    f.write(dumps({'n':1}))
    f.write(']')
```

It seems to also work if you dump with indent because the dump function doesn't end with a newline character in either case.

#### Handling an empty array

If, the first time you dumped the list, it was empty, resulting in an empty json array in the file "[]", then appending a comma like in my example will result in something like this "[,...] which you probably don't want.

The way I've seen this handled in the wild by protocols like [i3bar](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3bar-protocol.html) (wich use an unending json array to send information), is to always start with a header element. In their case they use `{ "version": 1 }`.

So ensure that you have that at the start of yours list when you do the first dump -- that is, unless you're sure you'll always have something in the list.

### Other notes

Even though this sort of manual json hack is used by projects like i3bar, I wouldn't personally reccomend doing this in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires that the list be closed with a `"]"` so its not natively appendable. You could try something tricky with opening the end of the file, removing the "]" and also fiddle with the new JSON you are trying to write. But that's messy.

An interesting thing about JSON is that the encoding doesn't have newlines. You can pretty print a JSON but if you don't, you can write an entire JSON record on a single line. So, instead of a JSON list, just have a bunch of lines, each of which is a JSON encoding of your dict.

```
def append_dict(filename, d):
    with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        fp.write(json.dumps(d))
        fp.write("\n")

def read_list(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        return [json.loads(line) for line in fp]
```

Since this file is now a bunch of JSON objects, not a single JSON list, any program expecting a single list in this file will fail.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Maybe just mention that this breaks compatibility with other programmes that are expecting a normal json file.