# Constantly append element to list in json file

Tags: python, json, list, append

Sorry if this is a very simple answer but I cannot find an answer to this question.

I have a very simple JSON file with a currently empty list.

```
{
    "times": [
        
    ]
}
```

In a while loop, i'd like to constantly append items to this list so that after the program is ended this file should look something like this.

```
{
    "times": [
        1.64,
        2.24,
        3.13,
        4.19
    ]
}
```

So in order to do this I tried out the following code and a couple other variations.

```
import json

while True:
    with open("data.json", "r") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
    datat.append("EXAMPLE")
    with open("data.json", "a") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Just looking at this, it looks very wrong.
My json file now looks like.

```
{
    "times": [

    ]
}["EXAMPLE"]
```

and I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/aspera/Documents/Eluv/live_stream_check/test.py", line 5, in
>
> data = json.load(jsonFile)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py",
> line 293, in load
> return loads(fp.read(),   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py",
> line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py",
> line 340, in decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 5 column 2 (char 25)

How can I append elements to a list in the json file (in a loop)?

Comment: You could just rewrite the entire JSON file, `with open("data.json", "w") as jsonFile:` Unless the file is getting large, this is fine. Otherwise, I think these answers are good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387575/append-to-list-of-dictionary-dumped-in-json-without-loading-the-list-out-with-py

Comment: you can't `append` directly to JSON file. You have to read JSON file into memory, update data in memory, and write all data back to file with write-mode `"w"` instead of append-mode `"a"`.

Comment: BTW: and you have to append to `data["times"]` like `data["times"].append(4.19)`. Or `extend` with many elemens - like `data["times"].extend( [1.64, 2.24, 3.13, 4.19] )` or `data["times"] += [1.64, 2.24, 3.13, 4.19]`

Comment: This ended up working, reading the data, modifying it, then writing it to a file. Though I don't know about the part of opening the file so many times. Is it fine?