# Add, edit and delete from json file (library system)

Tags: python, json

For a project I'm creating an online library system. Now, I have loaded the books and all their info with a json file. The json file looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "author": "Unknown",
    "country": "Sumer and Akkadian Empire",
    "imageLink": "images/the-epic-of-gilgamesh.jpg",
    "language": "Akkadian",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh\n",
    "pages": 160,
    "title": "The Epic Of Gilgamesh",
    "ISBN": "978123438397",
    "year": -1700
  },
  {
    "author": "Unknown",
    "country": "Achaemenid Empire",
    "imageLink": "images/the-book-of-job.jpg",
    "language": "Hebrew",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Job\n",
    "pages": 176,
    "title": "The Book Of Job",
    "ISBN": "9781238427897",
    "year": -600
  },
  {
    "author": "Unknown",
    "country": "India/Iran/Iraq/Egypt/Tajikistan",
    "imageLink": "images/one-thousand-and-one-nights.jpg",
    "language": "Arabic",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Thousand_and_One_Nights\n",
    "pages": 288,
    "title": "One Thousand and One Nights",
    "ISBN": "9781234564897",
    "year": 1200
  },
  {
    "author": "Unknown",
    "country": "Iceland",
    "imageLink": "images/njals-saga.jpg",
    "language": "Old Norse",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nj%C3%A1ls_saga\n",
    "pages": 384,
    "title": "Nj\u00e1l's Saga",
    "ISBN": "9781234566827",
    "year": 1350
  },
  {
    "author": "Jane Austen",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "imageLink": "images/pride-and-prejudice.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pride_and_Prejudice\n",
    "pages": 226,
    "title": "Pride and Prejudice",
    "ISBN": "9781234955897",
    "year": 1813
  },
  {
    "author": "Honor\u00e9 de Balzac",
    "country": "France",
    "imageLink": "images/le-pere-goriot.jpg",
    "language": "French",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A8re_Goriot\n",
    "pages": 443,
    "title": "Le P\u00e8re Goriot",
    "ISBN": "9781234525797",
    "year": 1835
  },
  {
    "author": "Samuel Beckett",
    "country": "Republic of Ireland",
    "imageLink": "images/molloy-malone-dies-the-unnamable.jpg",
    "language": "French, English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molloy_(novel)\n",
    "pages": 256,
    "title": "Molloy, Malone Dies, The Unnamable, the trilogy",
    "ISBN": "9781234767747",
    "year": 1952
  },
  {
    "author": "Giovanni Boccaccio",
    "country": "Italy",
    "imageLink": "images/the-decameron.jpg",
    "language": "Italian",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decameron\n",
    "pages": 1024,
    "title": "The Decameron",
    "ISBN": "9781235622297",
    "year": 1351
  },
  {
    "author": "Jorge Luis Borges",
    "country": "Argentina",
    "imageLink": "images/ficciones.jpg",
    "language": "Spanish",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficciones\n",
    "pages": 224,
    "title": "Ficciones",
    "ISBN": "9781234562237",
    "year": 1965
  },
  {
    "author": "Emily Bront\u00eb",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "imageLink": "images/wuthering-heights.jpg",
    "language": "English",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuthering_Heights\n",
    "pages": 342,
    "ISBN": "9781234567897",
    "title": "Wuthering Heights",
    "year": 1847
  },
  {
    "author": "Albert Camus",
    "country": "Algeria, French Empire",
    "imageLink": "images/l-etranger.jpg",
    "language": "French",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(novel)\n",
    "pages": 185,
    "title": "The Stranger",
    "ISBN": "9781234562447",
    "year": 1942
  }
]
```

One of the requirements is to be able to add, edit and delete a book in the library system. I tried to program a function which adds a book to the system/json file, but it will append after the squared bracket in the json file. And I need it to append right before the last squared bracket. This is the piece of that is supposed add a book:

```
    def addBook(self):
         print("Please fill in the following information:")
         author = input("Author: ")
         country = input("Country: ")
         image = input("Image Link: ")
         lang = input("Language: ")
         link = input("Link: ")
         pages = int(input("Pages: "))
         title = input("Title: ")
         isbn = input("ISBN: ")
         year = int(input("Year: "))
         y =  { "author": author,
    "country": country,
    "imageLink": image,
    "language": lang,
    "link": link,
    "pages": pages,
    "title": title,
    "ISBN": isbn,
    "year": year
    }
         a_file = open("books.json", "a")
         json.dump(y, a_file)
         a_file.close()
```

Then I also tried to code a function that can edit the details of a book, but I failed miserably. First there is a feature which searches for the book you want, then I need to find a way to select a book:

```
def selectCatalogue(self):
      os.system('cls')
      bookInfo = input("Please fill the author or title of the book in: ")
      m = 1
      for i in data:
        if bookInfo.casefold() in i['author'].casefold():
          print('['+ str(m) + '] '+ 'Author: '+ i['author'])
          print('    ' + 'Country: ' + i['country']) 
          print('    ' + 'Image link: ' + i['imageLink']) 
          print('    ' + 'Language: ' + i['language'])    
          print('    ' + 'Link: ' + i['link']) 
          print('    ' + 'Pages: ' + str(i['pages'])) 
          print('    ' + 'Title: ' + i['title']) 
          print('    ' + 'ISBN: ' + i['ISBN']) 
          print('    ' + 'Year: ' + str(i['year'])) 
          print(' ') 
          m = m + 1
        if bookInfo.casefold() in i['title'].casefold():
          print('['+ str(m) + '] '+ 'Author: '+ i['author'])
          print('    ' + 'Country: ' + i['country']) 
          print('    ' + 'Image link: ' + i['imageLink']) 
          print('    ' + 'Language: ' + i['language'])    
          print('    ' + 'Link: ' + i['link']) 
          print('    ' + 'Pages: ' + str(i['pages'])) 
          print('    ' + 'Title: ' + i['title']) 
          print('    ' + 'ISBN: ' + i['ISBN']) 
          print('    ' + 'Year: ' + str(i['year'])) 
          print(' ') 
          m = m + 1
      choice = input("Please enter the number of the book you were looking for: ")
 #     if choice == m:
         #  need to find a way to select a book
```

Then I programmed a function which is supposed to be able to edit details of the book:

```
    def editBook(self):
      Catalogue().selectCatalogue()
      print("What do you want to edit? ")
      print('[1] Author')
      print('[2] Country') 
      print('[3] Image link') 
      print('[4] Language')    
      print('[5] Link') 
      print('[6] Pages') 
      print('[7] Title') 
      print('[8] ISBN')
      print('[9] Year')      
      choice = input()
      with open("books.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
         data = json.load(jsonFile)
 if choice == '1':
  #      with open("replayScript.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
   #       data = json.load(jsonFile)
       data["author"] = input("Please enter the new author name: ")
      if choice == '2':
        data["country"] = input("Please enter the new country name: ")
      if choice == '3':
        data["imageLink"] = input("Please enter the new image link: ")
      if choice == '4':
        data["language"] = input("Please enter the new language: ")
      if choice == '5':
        data["link"] = input("Please enter the new  link: ")
      if choice == '6':
        data["author"] = int(input("Please enter the new number of pages: "))
      if choice == '7':
        data["title"] = input("Please enter the new title: ")
      if choice == '8':
        data["ISBN"] = int(input("Please enter the new ISBN: "))  
      if choice == '9':
        data["year"] = int(input("Please enter the new year: "))
```

Lastly I need to make a function that can delete books, but I'm clueless.

Is there someone who can help me with this? I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

`Add` : Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387575/append-to-list-of-dictionary-dumped-in-json-without-loading-the-list-out-with-py), I think they explain quite well why you can't just append a new book to the end of your json.

You have a json with a list of dictionaries. If you want to add or delete a book, just get access to a single list element (which is a dictionary) and remove the element, or in case you want to add a book, load the data, append your new book and dump it back to json:

```
with open('your_json.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data.append(new_book) #new_book is the dict with the new book information

with open('new_json.json', 'w') as g:
    json.dump(data, g)
```

`SelectCatalogue()`:

You don't need to look twice for book or author, you can do that in one step.
At the end you have a variable choice, where you want to select a book by a number, I guess this is in case you have multiple books by one author and you want to select only one specific? You don't need that `m` as counter, just use `enumerate`, so you have a number (which is the list index of the dict) for each book.

```
def selectCatalogue():
    bookInfo = input("Please fill the author or title of the book in: ")
    for idx, dic in enumerate(data):
        if bookInfo.casefold() in [dic['author'].casefold(), dic['title'].casefold()]:
            print('['+ str(idx) + '] '+ 'Author: '+ dic['author'])
            print('    ' + 'Country: ' + dic['country']) 
            print('    ' + 'Image link: ' + dic['imageLink']) 
            print('    ' + 'Language: ' + dic['language'])    
            print('    ' + 'Link: ' + dic['link']) 
            print('    ' + 'Pages: ' + str(dic['pages'])) 
            print('    ' + 'Title: ' + dic['title']) 
            print('    ' + 'ISBN: ' + dic['ISBN']) 
            print('    ' + 'Year: ' + str(dic['year'])) 
            print(' ') 
    choice = int(input("Please enter the number of the book you were looking for: "))
    data[choice] # <-- this will get you access to one dict which you can print like above if you want 
    return choice
```

I added the return statement because you can use it in the `edit_book()` function to access the book you want to change information.

Here is the new edit function, which asks for book/author, then the number you want (and stores it), then asks which information you want to change, at the end dump the new json to a json file.

```
def editBook():
    book_idx = selectCatalogue() # you need it to access later when editing information
    print("What do you want to edit? ")
    print('[1] Author')
    print('[2] Country') 
    print('[3] Image link') 
    print('[4] Language')    
    print('[5] Link') 
    print('[6] Pages') 
    print('[7] Title') 
    print('[8] ISBN')
    print('[9] Year')      
    choice = input()
    with open("books.json", "r") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        
    # data is the whole list of dicts, you want to access one element of the list, book_idx added
    if choice == '1':
        data[book_idx]["author"] = input("Please enter the new author name: ")
    if choice == '2':
        data[book_idx]["country"] = input("Please enter the new country name: ")
    if choice == '3':
        data[book_idx]["imageLink"] = input("Please enter the new image link: ")
    if choice == '4':
        data[book_idx]["language"] = input("Please enter the new language: ")
    if choice == '5':
        data[book_idx]["link"] = input("Please enter the new  link: ")
    if choice == '6':
        data[book_idx]["author"] = int(input("Please enter the new number of pages: "))
    if choice == '7':
        data[book_idx]["title"] = input("Please enter the new title: ")
    if choice == '8':
        data[book_idx]["ISBN"] = int(input("Please enter the new ISBN: "))  
    if choice == '9':
        data[book_idx]["year"] = int(input("Please enter the new year: "))
    
    #write the edited list of dicts back to json
    with open('books_edited.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Regarding your last problem, deleting a book:
As you can see I accessed the dictionary with its list index in the other functions. For this task you just need to call the `selectCatalogue()` and save the chosen book index to a variable. Then delete that element `data[index]` and write the new data back to json.
You should be able to get that done by yourself now :)

Since you work in a class and I don't have it, I removed some of the parts to get it running. Don't forget to add it back to it.